# Writing Json Data to file in Azure Synapse PySpark Notebook

Tags: python, json, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I'm working on a project to extract data from an API using PySpark and save to a file in Azure Data Lake Gen 2. Yes, I know this should be simple and I'm having no trouble extracting the data, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what to do with it after I get it.

My process is as follows:

```
workspace_query = {'format': 'json'}
response = requests.get("https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspaces", headers={'Authorization': <some things InfoSec would appreciate that I didn't put in a public forum>}, params=workspace_query)

json_response = response.json()
kantata_json_data = json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Okay, so from here I can, if I so choose, print the contents of kantata_json_dumps (the details of which InfoSec would also appreciate if I didn't post in a public forum) and it all looks like JSON. Yay.

What I *can't* figure out from here is how to actually write the contents of that variable to a file successfully. Specifically, if I try to write, I get something along these lines:

```
with open("https://p4syndev.dfs.core.windows.net/<Auzre subscription stuff>/<my foldername>/", "w") as file:
outfile.write(kantata_json_data)
```

And then the error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [23], line 1
----> 1 with open("https://p4syndev.dfs.core.windows.net/<Auzre subscription stuff>/<my foldername>/", "w") as file:
      2     outfile.write(kantata_json_data)

File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:282, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    275 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    276     raise ValueError(
    277         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    278         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    279         "you can use builtins' open."
    280     )
--> 282 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is confusing because I had assumed that I'd be able to write to a folder with either the URL or ABFSS path but I get the same error for both. I'm new to Azure and there absolutely could be some secret sauce I'm missing here.

So I tried to write to a dataframe and then convert that to JSON (which seems frankly unpythonic but *whatever*) and recieved an IllegalArgumentException.

Any thoughts about how I should handle this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my json data.

[image]

You can use below code to write.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json_data))
df.to_json('abfs://dats/output/json_files/user.json', storage_options = {'linked_service' : 'AzureDataLakeStorage1'})
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Here I am creating pandas dataframe writing it to storage account using abfs protocal.

You can use path like any one of the following.

`abfs://<container_name>/<path_to_file>`

OR

`abfs://container_name@Storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_file`

And there will be linked service default in your synapse workspace. Give that name in storage options or if you created the linked service use that.

[image]

You cannot use this kind of protocols to access files using **open** function, because it searches files in local filesystem, that is pool you attached.